# VB.NET - any string to date conversion

Tags: vb.net, string, date, string-conversion

Short question. I am trying to convert a string into Date (to put it later into INSERT command). My problem is that the string I am reading is always different (there is no rule what format it is going to be - as this is user-dependent).

I found such piece of code on the stackoverflow:

```
DateTime myDate = 
    DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", 
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but in my case it will not work as I don't know what kind of format I am going to import.
Is there any universal import function which checks all known formats? If now how should I write it? (please give me some hints).

Thanks for any tips and hints in advance,
Pete

Comment: I'm not sure a universal function is possible. For example is 5/3/2011 May 3rrd or March 5th? Depends on where you live. Also, you will probably need to narrow down the formats you support. For example, would you want it to be able to convert "tomorrow" to a valid date?

Comment: The problem is, `2009-05-08` might be `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-dd-MM` - without extra information, you can't unambiguously convert that string to a date...

Comment: Or, even worse: `05/06/07`.  What part of that is year, month, and day? I know how that would typically be read in my part of the world, but absent more strict rules for the format that could be at least 4 different dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible however you may define possible `formats` in an array and pass it to `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` method.

```
Dim format() As String = {"dd-MM-yy", "dd/MM/yy"}

Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531",format, 
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: Is it reasonable if I put all formats in the format() and then test it in a loop and in case none of them fit - throw an exception?

Comment: @Pete - What if more than one format fits?  Do you just take the first one that does?  The last one?

Comment: Just right now I've checked my database. I use SQLCE where I use "datetime" format of my date cell. From another post from stackoverflow I've read that it's "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff". If more than 1 fits, I'll take the first one. Or I would take that one which will be accepted by that pattern I pasted over here.

Comment: @Pete The best approach is that you have to restrict a user to input a date in a specific format. There are so many ways - DateTimepicker, input mask etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't (or can't) validate the date as the user enters it (to ensure it is a valid date), then you're kind of screwed.

Taking locals into account, 1/2/2011 could be 1st Feb (Ireland, UK & Europe), or could be 2nd Jan (USA).

Even ignoring locals it can get hairy, some one puts in "Thursday 13/10/11", the 13th is Thursday fine, what if they get it wrong and put in "Friday 13/10/11", or they just put Friday 10/11, is that today (Friday 14th Oct 2011) or some Friday in November 2011.

Then you get the intuitive user that enters "Next Thursday", in theory you can handle that too, should you?

Then you get typos, 112//2011, is that 11/2/2011, or 1/12/2011?

There's too much going wrong here, do whatever you need to do to ensure the user input is valid, move heaven and earth if you must, but do this where the user enters the data.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your opinion. You are right to some extent, but in my case the dates will be imported from an excel file. Maybe in the Excel itself there is a cultureinfo stored somewhere?

Comment: @Pete: Sorry, me not speakie the Excelie :(

Comment: @Binary - How can 1/2/2001 be 1st Jan?  And how can it be 2nd Feb?  Typo perhaps?

Comment: Yep, typo, 1st Feb or 2nd Jan :)